# lein-ring plugin throws exception

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am trying to use lein-ring plugin. After having installed the plugin any attempt to issue a a lein ring command yields a

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory

I am using leiningen 1.7.1 and java version 1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML streaming API wasn't included in the standard JRE until Java 6. You've got a few options:

- Upgrade to Java 6+
- Download the JSR173 API [here](http://sjsxp.java.net/)
- Add `[javax.xml/jsr173 "1.0"]` to your Leiningen dependencies

Comment: adding [javax.xml/jsr173 "1.0"] to dev-dependencies seems to have solved the problem